# Spring MVC AJAX with Jquery cannot Retrieve json response

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring

I want to search an account via ajax. I have this on my client side.

```
<form id="fetchAccount">
    <input type="search" name="id"/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#fetchAccount').on('submit', function(e){

            var data = $(this).serialize();
            var header = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");
            var token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");

            $.ajax({
                data:data,
                type:"PUT",
                url:"fetchAccout",
                dataType : 'json',
                contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                beforeSend: function(xhr){
                    xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);
                },
                success: function(response){
                    console.log(response);
                }
            });
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
</script>
```

And on the controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/fetchAccout", method=RequestMethod.PUT,
                produces= MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public Account fetchAccount(@RequestParam(value="id", required=false) Long id){
    Account account = null;
    if(id != null)
        account = custService.findAccountById(id);
    return account;
}
```

Im having a 200 HTTP response. i doubt that my mistake is in the client side. I cant even do an alert in the success function.

Answer (score 0):

Your return type is 200 that means success but i can see issue with your controller method. You are expecting to return a String but are actually returning Account, change it to following and try it.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/fetchAccout", method=RequestMethod.PUT,
                produces= MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public Account fetchAccount(@RequestParam(value="id", required=false) Long id){
    Account account = null;
    if(id != null)
        account = custService.findAccountById(id);
    return account;
}
```

That will return you a account object.
Then change your console output to return a Account parameter e.g. if it has number then get it to do this:

```
console.log(response.number);
```

Comment: oh sorry typo. I was actually doing this but still I cant see the response object..

Comment: Have you checked whether findAccountById actually returns anything? Is your id actually returning a null? I would take out the if(id != null) line and test it then as well.

Comment: oh well i found out the id im retrieving in the requestparam is null.

Comment: Ok so once you fix your id being null then the code i posted will work fine for you. Change your id input field to <input type="number" name="id"/> that will be a fix and will limit the user to inputing numbers only

Comment: the id is still null though i tried to input a number

Comment: Open the developer console and check what the parameters being passed are. For all you know your serialisation is either not picking up the data or is submiting under different parameters. Try doing $('#fetchAccount').serialize() instead of $(this).serialize() and verify the results.

Comment: i tried to alert(data) and it gives me id=1 (correct result)

Comment: Can you paste in your whole serialised string

Comment: i only have 1 input
id=1

Comment: In your dev console when it submits what is the exact string it submits.

Comment: i dont really see anything in the console.

Comment: If you not seeing "<yourdomain>/fetchAccount" at least means your $.ajax code is not being called. You should be at least be seeing "<yourdomain>/fetchAccount" to indicate its submitting a PUT request to your controller code.

Comment: @JasperBernales did you end up resolving this issue?